# VS2010 has stopped generating <AppName>.exe.config file after building

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, app-config

I have console app to host the WCF service for testing purpose. Everything was fine, until a few days. Every time I build any EXE project for .NET Framework 4, VS2010 (MSBuild) has stopped generating AppName.exe.config file.

Does anyone know, what and where to look for to enable or check the generation of AppName.exe.config file? The app.config in my C# console project has Build Action set to None.

I can add programmatic configurations for my WCF service, but I want to first solve the problem of my VS2010 not generating exe.config file.

Thanks.

Comment: MSBuild will copy the AppName.config file to the bin directory, and rename it to AppName.exe.config. I'm assuming that you don't have an AppName.config file in your project directory anymore.

Comment: I do have App.config in all my exe projects, but my VS2010 just does not produce '<AppName>.exe.config'. I created an console project from scratch, built it and the output dir (bin\Debug) did not have the exe.config file.

Answer (score 0):

I had this one time.

My memory is loose on this one.

It was either:

1. I deleted the App.config file.  Then readded it.
   or
2. I created a new Console App, and moved all my files over to it.

It was a "fluke", not sure what the magic voodoo was.  Just know I did ~something to make it work again.

Comment: I had done the first option, but no luck. For your second option, I did something very similar, I created a console app from scratch just to see whether VS2010 builds outputting AppName.exe.config, but it did not.

This is now happening to all my previous EXE projects, none of them now generates exe.config after build, I guess something have caused my VS2010 Build (MSBuild) malfunctioning.